Antd theme not applying consistently to all components
My usecase is i want to build custom component and use it in the primary package. apply a theme from the primrary package that can also be used by my custom component as well.
but for some reason the custom package is not able to get the theme applied to primrary package.
I have two button one inside my custom component package
//PackageA-Custom Component 

import { Button } from "antd"

export default function HelloWorld() {
  return (
    <Button type="primary" style={{ width: 200 }}>Demo button</Button>)
}

and PackageB which uses PackageA
  <React.StrictMode>
    <ConfigProvider
      theme={componentConfig1}>
      <Button type="primary">Demo button s1</Button><br />
      <!-- This loads  the HelloWorldcomponent --> 
      <RouterProvider router={MyRoutesSettings()} />
    </ConfigProvider>
  </React.StrictMode>,

Below is my Config for theme
export const componentConfig1: ThemeConfig = {
  // hashed: false,
  token: {
    colorPrimary: "#237804",
  },
  components: {
    Card: {
      headerBg: "#F9F9F9",
      headerFontSize: 20,
    },
    Button: {
      fontSize: 15,
      fontWeight: "700",
    },
  },

But i see the buttons are generated with differrent color

i also checked the hashes classes for this buttons are differrent

class="ant-btn css-dev-only-do-not-override-13oz7a8 ant-btn-primary"
class="ant-btn css-dev-only-do-not-override-1okl62o ant-btn-primary"

Any Hints/Suggeston on how can i make them consistent.

I am not sure if this is right way to do it but this solved my problem
I added this this made the css for both button same.

theme={{ inherit:true, cssVar : {prefix:"someprefix", key:"samplekey"} }}


as soon as there is change in the page(some type in input box somewhere..) , this breaks. so not a working solution

I ended up creating a instance of theme and sharing with the library module with static intialization

I have the same issue and looking for some kind of solution as of now
